# Mostrar datos de una tabla MySQL en varias tablas separadas

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una tabla en MySQL donde almaceno los nombres de los países participantes del mundial de Qatar 2022.

```
CREATE TABLE teams (
    id int(36) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    grupo varchar(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO `teams` VALUES
('1', 'Qatar', 'A'),('2', 'Ecuador', 'A'),('3', 'Senegal', 'A'),('4','Paises Bajos', 'A'),
('5', 'Inglaterra', 'B'),('6', 'Iran', 'B'),('7', 'Estados Unidos', 'B'),('8','Gales', 'B'),
('9', 'Argentina', 'C'),('10', 'Arabia Saudita', 'C'),('11', 'Mexico', 'C'),('12','Polonia', 'C'),
('13', 'Francia', 'D'),('14', 'Australia', 'D'),('15', 'Dinamarca', 'D'),('16', 'Tunez', 'D'),
('17', 'España', 'E'),('18', 'Costa Rica', 'E'),('19', 'Alemania', 'E'),('20','Japon', 'E'),
('21', 'Belgica', 'F'),('22', 'Canada', 'F'),('23', 'Marruecos', 'F'),('24','Croacia', 'F'),
('25', 'Brasil', 'G'),('26', 'Serbia', 'G'),('27', 'Suiza', 'G'),('28','Camerun', 'G'),
('29', 'Portugal', 'H'),('30', 'Ghana', 'H'),('31', 'Uruguay', 'H'),('32','Corea del Sur', 'H');
```

Lo que necesito es mostrar los países por grupo, en formato de tabla, por lo que serían 8 grupos (tablas) de 4 países cada uno.

```
<?php 
    require '../account/database.php';

    $sql = "SELECT nombre FROM teams LIMIT 4";   
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $results = $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
?>

<div>
    <table border-table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody>
            <?php
                foreach($results as $result) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <th><?php echo $result -> nombre ?></th>
            </tr>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Considere crear 8 tablas distintas, cada una con los 4 países de cada grupo, y a partir de eso mostrar las tablas una por una, pero antes quería saber si existía alguna alternativa más optimizada. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedes usar procedimientos almacenados, un SP donde reciba un parámetro con la letra del grupo A, luego la del B y así vas 'pintándolos' en tu fronted.

Comment: No se como funciona esto, podrías explicarlo mas a fondo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
<?php 
    require '../account/database.php';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM teams ORDER BY grupo,nombre";   
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $results = $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $grupos = [];
    $nombre_grupos = [];
    foreach($results as $row) {
        $grupos[$row->grupo][] = $row->nombre;
        $nombre_grupos[$row->grupo] = 1;
    }
?>

<div>
<?php
    foreach(array_keys($nombre_grupos) as $codigo_grupo) {
?>
    <table border-table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Grupo <?= $codigo_grupo ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody>
            <?php
                foreach($grupos[$codigo_grupo] as $nombre) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $nombre ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php
    }
?>
</div>
```

### Cambios realizados

1. Donde ponías esto:

```
$sql = "SELECT nombre FROM teams LIMIT 4";
```

lo he cambiado por esto:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM teams ORDER BY grupo,nombre";
```

para tenerlos todos ordenados por grupo y nombre de una sola tacada y que sea el PHP el que los vaya delimitando (sino tendrias que hacer muchas consultas SQL).

2. Después he recorrido la consulta para crear una variables tipo array que contengan los datos de forma estructurada para los siguientes bucles de este modo:

```
    $grupos = [];
    $nombre_grupos = [];
    foreach($results as $row) {
        $grupos[$row->grupo][] = $row->nombre;
        $nombre_grupos[$row->grupo] = 1;
    }
```

con eso conseguimos dos arrays, una que contiene los nombres de cada grupo ($grupos) y otra que tan solo contiene los nombres de los grupos en sus índices ($nombre_grupos).

3. Después, para crear una tabla para cada grupo, he creado un bucle que recorre la variable $nombre_grupos y en cada recorrido creamos una tabla y agregamos los nombres en otro bucle más adelante:

```
    foreach(array_keys($nombre_grupos) as $codigo_grupo) {
```

de este modo, usando array_keys(), sacamos los nombres de los grupos.

4. Ya que sacamos esos nombres vamos a ponerlos en el thead de la tabla para que se vean bien:

```
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Grupo <?= $codigo_grupo ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
```

5. Y después ya podemos recorrer el otro array multidimensional pasándole consultándole sólo el índice del grupo que estamos recorriendo actualmente para sacar sus nombres:

```
foreach($grupos[$codigo_grupo] as $nombre) {
```

6. Y así en cada ciclo hasta terminar con los 4 grupos. Lo cual nos crear 4 tablas con todos los grupos y sus nombres correspondientes, que es loq ue el OP ha preguntado.

Comment: No me funciono, hay variables que no están declaradas.

Comment: ¿que variables no estan declaradas?  ¿Seguro que has copiado exactamente lo que yo he puesto en mi respuesta?  Vale, puede ser esta: `foreach($grupo[$codigo_grupo]` la cual deberia es `foreach($grupos[$codigo_grupo]`... ahora lo arreglo en la respuesta

Comment: Warning: Undefined variable $_null on line 18

Comment: jolin, si que me equivoque en cosas... no es asi: `$codigo_grupo->$_null`  sino así: `$codigo_grupo=>$_null`

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, saludos y gracias por haber ayudado!

Comment: Bien, me alegro que te haya servido, acabo de agregar la explicación pertinente para que la respuesta sea completa. Saludos!  (he hecho un par de cambios más que he visto para mejorarla también).

Answer (score 0):

esto podria ser un comentario pero como no puedo comentar por mi reputacion lo dejare como respuesta.

La opcion mas sencilla en este caso es que tengas un tabla llamada grupos, en este tendrias 8 instancias de esta tabla con los 4 equipos en cada una. por lo que se entiende tu BD deberia de tener una estructura como la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teams (
    id          bigint AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    nombre      varchar(100) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_teams PRIMARY KEY (id)
)ENGINE=InnoDb;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS group_fase (
    id          bigint AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    nombre      varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    equipo1_id  bigint NOT NULL,
    equipo2_id  bigint NOT NULL,
    equipo3_id  bigint NOT NULL,
    equipo4_id  bigint NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_group_fase PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT fk_equipo1_teams FOREIGN KEY(equipo1_id) REFERENCES teams(id),
CONSTRAINT fk_equipo2_teams FOREIGN KEY(equipo2_id) REFERENCES teams(id),
CONSTRAINT fk_equipo3_teams FOREIGN KEY(equipo3_id) REFERENCES teams(id),
CONSTRAINT fk_equipo4_teams FOREIGN KEY(equipo4_id) REFERENCES teams(id)
)ENGINE=InnoDb;
```

en base a esto podras llamar a la tabla 'fase_grupo' que por cada instancia contendra el nombre del grupo y a traves de las foreign key llamar a los equipos para obtener sus atributos, como de esta forma:

```
 $sql = "SELECT *, (SELECT nombre FROM teams WHERE id = equipo1_id) AS equipo1,
 (SELECT nombre FROM teams WHERE id = equipo2_id) AS equipo2,
 (SELECT nombre FROM teams WHERE id = equipo3_id) AS equipo3,
 (SELECT nombre FROM teams WHERE id = equipo4_id) AS equipo4,
 FROM group_fase ORDER BY nombre ASC";   
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results = $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

y por ultimo el codigo html como esto

```
<div>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Grupo</th>
            <th>Equipo 1</th>
            <th>Equipo 2</th>
            <th>Equipo 3</th>
            <th>Equipo 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
        foreach($fase_grupo as $grupo) {
            <tr>
                <td><?= $grupo->nombre ?></td>
                <td><?= $grupo->equipo1 ?></td>
                <td><?= $grupo->equipo2 ?></td>
                <td><?= $grupo->equipo3 ?></td>
                <td><?= $grupo->equipo4 ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Lo intenté pero tengo problemas para mostrar los datos en la página. Adjunto foto de la base de datos: [enlace](https://prnt.sc/1QNDwwsd-7s3)

Comment: cual es el problema que estas teniendo en estos momento, por la imagen no puedo saber que es lo que necesitas hacer y que es lo que te esta causando un problema.